# kotlin IntelliJ IDEA main function not returning anything

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I am trying to learn Kotlin. While working my way through Kotlin Bootcamp for Programmers by Google I have encountered an issue with functions.

A simple Hello World function that I have added in separate kotlin script when ran does not return anything.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, world!")
}
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YrlD.png)

In addition I am getting warning:
*WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil*

I was able to find solution which requires adding following line to gradle.properties but it seems not to work.
*org.gradle.jvmargs=-Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options=--illegal-access=permit*

Project JDK is coretto-15, IntelliJ IDEA is up to date.
I am also curious why kotlin files have .kts extension while everywhere I look it says it should be .kt

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think in a .kts file, you don't need the `main` function declaration at all. Just write `println(...)` and it will run. The `main` function is the entry point for kotlin programs in .kt files.

Comment: Okay, if I omit main function it does show what I want. 
Are .kt files gone for good or can I create such file if I want to? 
I have found a following tutorial from March 2021 which still shows .kt files.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-your-first-kotlin-app.html

Comment: No one ever said anything about .kt files being gone so I don't know where you got that idea from.

Comment: I came to this conclusion because I can create only two types of Kotlin files. I have no idea how I could create a file with .kt extension.
Kotlin Script - [name].kts
Kotlin Worksheet - [name].ws.kts

Comment: Okay, I was able to create .kt files after marking directory as Sources root. Thank you for your answer. You were completely right about .kts files and main function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the Kotlin sources under the `src/main/kotlin` directory. But you have created in under the `src` directory, which is not the source root. See also [Kotlin and Java sources﻿](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#kotlin-and-java-sources).